# Correct Encoding for Classification (label)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm putting data into a randomforest classifier.

```
#create bins for interval measures
n = 0
interval_length = 30
bins = []

while interval_length*n < interval_length + features['Cycle Time'].max():
    x = interval_length*n
    bins.append(x)
    n = n+1

features["Cycle Time Interval"] = pd.cut(features['Cycle Time'], bins)
```

I run my model:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(features_encoded, features["Cycle Time Interval"])
```

And get this error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'
```

It seems that the classifer doesn't like predicting the 'Cycle Time Interval' because of it's type (category).

Suggestions on encoding options or other solutions?

Comment: Can you show a sample of what `features['Cycles Time Interval']` contains? I.e., only a few categories?

Comment: Huh. Apparently this is a thing that might help?  [kbinsdiscretizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer.html)

Comment: @FChm an example would be [0,30), [30, 60), [60,90), etc.
Cycle Time Interval shows dtype as "category"

Comment: @G.Anderson this looks promising, but instead of choosing the number of bins, I want to choose the interval (in my example above it's 30).... any thoughts to how I could do that?

Comment: @MadelineKinnaird unfortunately I haven't used it myself, I just happened across it so I don't think I can tell you much more, other than maybe you could use your intervals to set the number of bins? Or, as in the example you provided above, one-hot encoding should work for a small number of intervals